# Masking Structure Name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I'm trying to mask a structure name like so:

```
#define cat_val(l, r) l##r
#define name_mask cat_val(exception_, __COUNTER__)

using i_dont_show_in_rtti = struct name_mask
{
// ...
};

void test()
{
    throw i_dont_show_in_rtti{};
}
```

This works, but only individually in files. If I include a file that has done this, I'll get a naming conflict (since `__COUNTER__` resets per file).

What are my other options? Is there another way I can just mutate a name so it's unintelligable yet unique without making my code unreasonably ugly?

Comment: Do you just want to `throw` a unique type each time?

Comment: @cigien No, I'd like it to be the same type, so that I may catch it. But I do not want the actual name to show in the RTTI, so I'd like it to just be a generic `exception_55`

Comment: `unintelligable yet unique` I would also add "*easily reversible for the maintainer*" to the list of requirements. If someone reports seeing an `exception_55` it should be easy for *you* to track that down to the actual source. A scheme based on global counters would not necessarily make that easy.

Comment: What is the reason you want to mask the names? For finding them you could manage your exceptions in namespaces.

Comment: @BerndBaumanns Static Analysis resistance

Comment: You could try to disable RTTI completely. This is done for example by the llvm project. MSVC, clang and g++ support it by a compiler switch. But than you can't use typeid and dynamic_cast...

Comment: @BerndBaumanns MSVC’s Disable RTTI is a joke

Comment: You mean, because after deactivating RTTI you can still find some? To remove it completely you need to disable exceptions, too. But....

Comment: @BerndBaumanns Disabling exceptions to completely disable rtti has proven more difficult than i expected

Comment: And I need / or want exceptions. So I can't disable them, too. In my project I disabled RTTI but not for obfuscation reasons - just to reduce the binary size. The answer from "n. 'pronouns' m." is really great. But perhaps you should have a look at some obfuscation frameworks, like this https://github.com/fritzone/obfy.

Comment: Those frameworks require too much coding overhead. I prefer using things like VMProtect and Themida

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do this in completely standard C++14.

```
  #include <cstdlib>

  template <std::size_t N>
  constexpr std::size_t ct_hash(const char (&str)[N])
  {
      std::size_t hash = 0;
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
          hash = (hash << 7) + (str[i] * str[i]); // just an example
      return hash;
  }

  template <std::size_t ... hashes>
  struct mangled;


  // don't have to use all of these, it's just an example. may use __COUNTER__ instead of __LINE__.
  #define HIDE_STRUCT(S) \
  using S = struct mangled<ct_hash(__FILE__), __LINE__, ct_hash(__DATE__), ct_hash(__TIME__), ct_hash(#S)>; \
  template <> struct mangled<ct_hash(__FILE__), __LINE__, ct_hash(__DATE__), ct_hash(__TIME__), ct_hash(#S)>

  HIDE_STRUCT(foo)
  {
      int a;
  };

  HIDE_STRUCT(bar)
  {
      int a; char b;
  };

  void test()
  {
      throw foo{};
  }

  void test2()
  {
      throw bar{};
  }
```

If you are concerned about possible hash collisions, you can reversibly encrypt your strings instead of hashing them, but this may require C++20 relaxed non-type template parameters (so that you can parametrise over an encrypted string). You will have to write a compile-time encryption function.

Comment: What does this look like in rdata?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your comment about using `__COUNTER__` instead of `__LINE__` is incorrect. If this is defined in a header file, then `__COUNTER__` may be different for each translation unit including it -- which would cause a new definition with different names, making it not possible to be used on APIs unless it's one giant file

Comment: Actually, hashing `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` would also do the same thing too -- since different translation units might be built at different times (incremental building)

Comment: @Human-Compiler yes if you need it in several TUs, date and time should not be used.

Comment: The point is to get something that'll work across separate translation units. Although this does have the underlying idea to just hash the name and use it as a template argument.